systemd user-defined specifier?
In a systemd unit template file, I know I can use "%i" (or "%I") to substitute the instance name.
But suppose I want to calculate some options from the instance name; e.g. a port number and/or IP address for a .socket unit.
Is this possible? For example, can I substitute the output of a program to calculate an option value?

No, but of course you could have a script of your own run as PreExec=, do these calculations, and e.g. write them to a settings file that your Exec= uses. Or your Exec= is just such a script, starting the actual executable with the desired options, but that comes with caveats, as your Unit Type= might really dictate the thing started through Exec= should be the actual daemon process, directly (e.g. for stopping reasons, or for knowing-when-it-started or -finished-starting reasons).
You can also use your shell and use command expansions (mydaemon -port $(instance_name_to_number %i) style), but the same considerations apply.

In my case, I want the ListenStream and possibly BindToDevice options to be computed, so none of these work-arounds applies.
Soapbox: This is my problem with the systemd design in general. Unlike every other Unix design since the beginning of time, systemd is extremely poor at supporting use cases the author did not specifically contemplate.
Thanks for your answer. I will just create N separate unit files.

@Nemo I understand the problem with your use case, but frankly, completely disagree with the systemd rant :) The fact alone that embedded device designers love it, because it brings up systems in reliable manners and fails beautifully when it can't, while desktop distros love it, because it's highly adaptable to anything the user in their craziness might plug into them at runtime kind of proves the "not adaptable to unforeseen use cases" wrong. But: that doesn't change the fact that it doesn't cover your use case.

The problem here is that it's important to the socket activation idea in systemd that socket properties are statically identifiable. The fact that you can't run something to calculate them is certainly an oversight, but tell me how you'd done that in a different system (say, xinetd) without extending it with your own code… nobody has foreseen your use case, so it's up to you to implement it! I'd have a recommendation, though: What about a different unit, which calculates the correct port parameter and itself instantiates a template unit that takes the port as parameter?

(I haven't tested that, it's a detour, so I might be missing something)
